# How to switch css class with CSSComponents

Tags: reactjs

I have an element with

```
className={this.props.shapeType}
```

Now this `shapeType` changes to `Square` and `Diamond`, so the result is `class="square"` or `class="diamond"`

The thing is that I´m using `CSSComponents` so to get a class from my .css I have to do:

```
className={s.NameOfTheClass}
```

where s comes from `import s from ./someStyle.css`

So square and diamond are not being applied and I can´t make:

```
className={s.this.props.shapeType}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `import * as s from './someStyle.css'` and try: `s[this.props.shapeType]`

Comment: You have written `className={s[this.props.shapeType]}` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed something, Right, It works!

Comment: Great!. Please mark it correct and resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all classes in `s`

```
import * as s from './someStyle.css';
```

and then use `s` object with className as key to get class:

```
s[this.props.shapeType]
```